# Global functions or macros to get Qt version in QML code

Tags: c++, qt, qml

How Can I get Qt version, for example `5.11.2` or similar, in my QML code. In my C++ code I have these options:

Method available on C++:

```
qVersion();
```

Macro available on C++:

```
QT_VERSION
```

But I couldn't find anything on QML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a Context Property, as explained [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html).

A simple example, given a simple qml file like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {

    Text {
        text: qtversion
    }

    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

Set the `qtversion` property at startup, in `main` function:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("qtversion", QString(qVersion()));
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;    

    return app.exec();
}
```